# Different input type based on data type of column in listview in wicket

Tags: user-interface, listview, wicket, wicket-6, presentation-layer

I am having a list of InputColumnsVO which will have column name and column datatype attributes..I am thinking to iterate this list of input columns object using Listview and display input boxes based on the column data type.For example:

```
if datatype is date,
        display DateTextField,
if datatype is numeric,
        display dropdown,
if datatype is string, 
       display a textfield.
```

Is this achievable in wicket?or is there an alternative way to the design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the type add a Panel that contains the respective form component. If the HTML markup is really simple and you don't want to have a special Panel for it then use a Fragment instead.

Comment: Yes, I think in this case fragments give you a better, more manageable result. But anything more complex and you're better off switching to panels. Particularly if you want to be able to test your components in isolation.

Comment: After displaying the n number of columns with its own input type  i have an add button which on click should create the same no of columns with same input types n delete should remove it..hw does that need to be handled

Comment: By duplicating the model at the server side and re-rendering the Form.

Answer (score 0):

We do it in a similar way: we have a listview/dataview of configuration options that populates the item with a widget retrieved from a factory for creating editors based on datatype of that option. Factory returns FormComponent/FormComponentPanel/Panel that we add to the item.

Comment: Can you please post an example of using fragment for different field type?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing real. We almost don't use fragments - we like having extra markup files, it's easier to locate markup for us that way. But using fragments it's similar to using panels. You just need to put them in a container tha is available at the fragment instantiation time (e.g. one panel containing them all).